# String Isolation Class

Tags: c#, performance, strings, socket

As a lone developer I don't really have anyone to peer review my work in-house so I was hoping someone could take a look at this class and tell me in what ways I could improve it.

Essentially what this class does is receive a string from a socket that could possibly have multiple messages in it and isolates these messages based on the message terminator. In the isolate message method, it acquires the number of terminators with split and then loops through and adds the substring to the list of messages. Afterwards it removes that substring from the data string.

Off the top of my head the first opts I spot are using an array based off the terminator count instead of a list and making the terminator string array global so it's not making a new array each time.

```
internal class MessageHandler
{
    const string m_MessageTerminator = "<|>";
    int m_TerminatorLength = m_MessageTerminator.ToArray().Length;

    internal void ProcessStream(SocketState state)
    {
        ///Extract individual messages from socket message queue.
        ProcessMessages(IsolateMessages(state.MessageQueue.ToString()));

        //Find the last index of the message terminator and remove the substring from the string builder.
        //We do not want to clear the string builder because it could have partial messages inside.
        int lastTerminatorIndex = state.MessageQueue.ToString().LastIndexOf(m_MessageTerminator);
        state.MessageQueue.Remove
            (0, lastTerminatorIndex + m_TerminatorLength);
    }

    internal string[] IsolateMessages(string data)
    { 
        List<string> messages = new List<string>();
        string[] terminators = new string[] { m_MessageTerminator };
        int terminatorCount = data.Split(terminators, StringSplitOptions.None).Length -1;

        for(int i = 0; i < terminatorCount; i++)
        {
            //Find The First Instance Of Message Termination
            int terminatorIndex = data.IndexOf(m_MessageTerminator);

            //Extract The Message Based On Terminator's Index
            //Then Remove The Terminator From The Message.
            messages.Add(data.Substring
                (0, terminatorIndex + m_TerminatorLength)
                    .Remove(terminatorIndex, m_TerminatorLength));

            //Remove The Message We Just Extracted From Overall Data Set
            data = data.Remove(0, terminatorIndex + m_TerminatorLength);
        }

        if (messages.Count > 0)
            return messages.ToArray();
        else
            return null;
    }

    internal void ProcessMessages(string[] messages)
    {
        if (messages == null)
            return;

        for(int i = 0; i < messages.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(messages[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please give a brief explanation of what this code is supposed to do, and what environment it is supposed to run in? You don't have any comments so it's time-consuming to figure out the logic.

Comment: Should I comment the code or explain it in paragraph form? My apologies. @Snowbody

Comment: What's the definition of `SocketState` and `MessageQueue`? Your `MessageQueue` seems to be quite different than the .NET Framework's `System.Messaging.MessageQueue`, right?

Comment: Code comments always help. But you really are supposed to explain the purpose of the code and briefly the logic in prose.

Comment: The socketstate is just an object that that has a buffer, socket, identifier, and stringbuilder. The MessageQueue is that string building. It's what gets populated when data comes in from the socket stream, that's why I named it that.. I'm open to naming convention suggestions :P

Comment: @Snowbody I added comments to the code.

Comment: You can replace `int m_TerminatorLength = m_MessageTerminator.ToArray().Length;` with `private static readonly int m_TerminatorLength = m_MessageTerminator.Length;` Also, prefixes like `m_` are out of use. I'd call them `MessageTerminator` and `MessageTerminatorLength`.

Comment: I'd also isolate reading from the queue and processing messages into separate classes. Perhaps one class to read from the queue. Another that processes messages, but all it's really doing is splitting the string and handing off the pieces to another class that actually processes the messages.

Comment: Could you please show the form in which the messages arrive. Is each message terminated like `"first<|>second<|> third<|>forth <|> last <|>"`. What should happen if the arrived data look like `"first<|>second<|> third<|>forth <|><|>"`  or `"first"`

Comment: Are you in control of the protocol? You may want to look into using [WCF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-wcf) or something from [System.Messaging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), maybe even [MessageQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### `IsolateMessages()`

You are creating a lot of strings here. Each time you call `Substring()`, or `.Remove()` on a `string` you are creating a new string. In addition the readability of

> ```
> messages.Add(data.Substring
>     (0, terminatorIndex + m_TerminatorLength)
>         .Remove(terminatorIndex, m_TerminatorLength));
> ```

is very very bad.

- By returning an `IEnumerable<string>` instead of `string[]` the execution of that method can be deffered by using `yield`.
- By using the overloaded `IndexOf(int, int)` you could omit the `terminatorCount` and replace the `for` loop by a `while` loop.

Applying these two points would lead to this beautyful code

```
internal IEnumerable<string> IsolateMessages(string data)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data)) { yield break; }

    var currentIndex = 0;
    var terminatorIndex = -1;

    while ((terminatorIndex = data.IndexOf(m_MessageTerminator, currentIndex)) > 0)
    {
        var messageLength = terminatorIndex - currentIndex;

        yield return data.Substring(currentIndex, messageLength);

        currentIndex = terminatorIndex + m_TerminatorLength;
    }
}
```

the only difference to your code is that if there is no message or the passed `string data` is empty my message isn't returning `null` so you could change the `ProcessMessages()` like

```
internal void ProcessMessages(IEnumerable<string> messages)
{
    foreach(var message in messages)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Comments inline

- > ```
  > const string m_MessageTerminator = "<|>";
  > int m_TerminatorLength = m_MessageTerminator.ToArray().Length;
  > ```

  1. `string` instances actually have a `.Length` property already -- you don't have to cast it to an array first.
  2. Why is the terminator member declared as `const`, but the terminator length member is not? What's your intent? At least make it `readonly`.
- > ```
  > ///Extract individual messages from socket message queue.
  > ```

  You have the syntax for documentation comments wrong. Please see [this tutorial.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/xml-documentation-comments)
- > ```
  > ProcessMessages(IsolateMessages(state.MessageQueue.ToString()));
  > ```

  1. Is `MessageQueue` a property or a field (member variable)? It's not readonly, right? So...
  2. Why convert the `StringBuilder MessageQueue` to a `string` here? You are writing `IsolateMessages()`, so just pass it as-is without copying.
  3. Since `ProcessMessages()` is just going to `foreach` over the collection of messages, the collection (both the input parameter to `ProcessMessages() and the return type of`IsolateMessages()`) should be of type`IEnumerable`and then`IsolateMessages()`will use`yield return`. Please see [this tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield). That way the whole list doesn't need to remain in memory for the duration of things. This is called "lazh evaluation"; execution gets suspended until the next chunk is actually needed. Often resulting in a memory savings, which may result in increased performance due to better caching. Have to test it though.
- > ```
  > int lastTerminatorIndex = state.MessageQueue.ToString().LastIndexOf(m_MessageTerminator);
  > state.MessageQueue.Remove(0, lastTerminatorIndex + m_TerminatorLength);
  > ```

  This seems like work that `IsolateMessages()` could do.
- > ```
  > internal string[] IsolateMessages(string data)
  > ```

  I reiterate my suggestion that this return an `IEnumerable<string>` and use `yield return` rather than building a `List<string>` and then converting it to a `string[]`.
- > ```
  > string[] terminators = new string[] { m_MessageTerminator };
  > ```

  This should be defined (and marked `readonly`) at the same place as `m_MessageTerminator`. It isn't going to change.
- > ```
  > int terminatorCount = data.Split(terminators, StringSplitOptions.None).Length -1;
  > ```

  Arrgh! What a waste! What a duplication of effort! The rest of the function after this point does the **exact same thing** as `string.Split()`, whose return value you just threw away. [Check out the documentation.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.1)
- > ```
  >   messages.Add(data.Substring(0, terminatorIndex + m_TerminatorLength).Remove(terminatorIndex, m_TerminatorLength));
  > ```

  Quite aside from the previous bullet point, this line makes no sense. The code deliberately adds on `m_TerminatorLength` characters, then removes them again.
- > ```
  >    data = data.Remove(0, terminatorIndex + m_TerminatorLength);
  > ```

  If you're going to be doing a lot of operations on text, you should do it in a `StringBuilder`, because each time you do so you create and destroy temporary strings, wasting speed and memory. But you really don't have to. Just keep track of the index and do just one remove at the end. (Heslacher showed you this in his answer)
- > ```
  >        if (messages.Count > 0)
  >         return messages.ToArray();
  >     else
  >         return null;
  > ```

  Why a null return here? Wouldn't a 0-element array be better? Then you wouldn't need a special case in `ProcessMessages`.

Comment: PascalCase is also used for (public) properties and fields, not just for methods and classes. Regarding `yield`, I think it's important to note that this makes a method 'lazy': it only does work when the result is actually iterated. This may cause problems in some cases if one is not aware of the difference (work not being done, or being done multiple times).